# Rails Formtastic FormBuilder Customize Markup?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

Does anyone know if there are hooks for customizing the output of formtastic?

Currently if I do something like this:

```
= form.input :name, :label => "Name"
```

It will render a list item:

```
<li id="item_name_input" class="string required">
    <label for="item_name">Name<abbr title="required">*</abbr></label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="item[name]" maxlength="255" id="item_name">
</li>
```

I want to get rid of the li wrapper (and parent ol) and replace with a div. Can't seem to find anything on the formtastic wiki about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you fork formtastic and change this [line](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic/blob/master/lib/formtastic.rb#L135), I don't think there's any way to do this. Formtastic's philosophy bases on [Aaron Gustafson Presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/AaronGustafson/learning-to-love-forms-web-directions-south-07), which shows this `ol` way to code forms.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with [this](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic/commit/7687bf7648c3c235760a89935bab57c170643a88) commit Formtastic supports modifying and customizing inputs. Also, consider taking a look at [SimpleForm](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form), which is less strict about markup and css.